# Jquery: pushing a fixed positioned div down with expanding Div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery to expand a hidden div on click in my page.

I have another div which is a fixed position div which is the header in my page.

what i am trying to do is to expand the div and then push the header div and everything else in my page down as this expandable div expands.

I have tried the relative position for the fixed div but i need this div to be present on the screen at all times which is why i've given it a fixed position!

Here is a [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4nb1akuy/) to see what I mean.

The html structure is like this:

```
<div align="center" class="boxs">
<p id="welcome">Welcome</p>
</div>
<div id="bubs" data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed" data-theme='d'>
    <h1 id="reveal" class="header-title">Click Here</h1>
</div>
```

could someone please advise on how to achieve this?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Paulie_D, Yes, that is correct. however, not the way you did it as I will need to push down the rest of the content (other divs, images etc) in my page as the div expands. your example is very close to what I am trying to do but you are expanding the header which is a fixed position and when it expands, it overlaps other contents as opposed to pushing them down.

Comment: @Paulie_D, Yes, that does push the content down but now the header stays up (fixed position issue that I had in the first place)! as I mentioned before, I would need the header with the fixed position as well as all other contents of the page to move down or to be pushed down as the expanding div expands. you're first example was closer to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I can can get.

As I mentioned, the fixed div is *fixed* so it's not going anywhere unless you tell it to. You *could* animate the top position and margins and so forth but I think I just prefer toggling the position property from `fixed` to `relative`.

```js
$('#a-sidebar').click(function() {
  $('#bubs').toggleClass('down');
  $('.boxs').slideUp('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.

  });
});

$('#reveal').click(function() {
  $('#bubs').toggleClass('down');
  $('.boxs').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.boxs {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
#welcome {
  color: #F8F8F8;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#bubs.down {
  position: relative;
}
main {
  height: 250px;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" class="boxs">
  <p id="welcome">Welcome</p>
</div>
<div id="bubs" data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed" data-theme='d'>
  <h1 id="reveal" class="header-title">Click Here</h1>

</div>
<main></main>
```

Comment: This is it. this is exactly what I am trying to do. you're the man... But i don't know why when I run your code in my html page and when I close the expanding div, the header Jumps up instead of sliding up like in your example!

Comment: Just make sure that you have the toggleClass *before* the slding function...that's important. Other than that you'd have to reproduce what you have in a demo so we can diagnose.

Comment: it just jumps instead of smooth sliding up/down!! is it because I'm including the jquery mobile?

Comment: Actually, no I don't think so. It's a margin thing I think - just reseting the margins makes it slide - http://jsfiddle.net/Lpb2gnj6/

Comment: Yes, it is because of the jquery mobile because when I don't include the jquery mobile, it smoothly slides instead of jumping but I need the jquery mobile to be included in my page though!

Comment: No, even in your last example(jsfiddle) it jumps up as opposed to sliding up. when i don't include the jquery mobile in the jsfiddle, it slides up properly! I just need to know why jquery mobile causes this issue.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to animate the top value back to the original position with JQ.